# Url routing from Catch() in asp.net 4.0

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, .net-4.0, url-routing

I have written in my content page

```
   protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Page.Title = "Bollywood Movie-" + Page.RouteData.Values["MovieName"].ToString();
            int movieid = int.Parse(Page.RouteData.Values["MovieId"].ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.RedirectToRoute("ErrorPage");
        }
    }
```

but after going into catch it doesn't redirect to error page but it goes to page_load then page_load of master then it shows error of

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
```

Input string was not in a correct format.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

what is wrong???

Answer (score 0):

You need to register the routes in `application_start` event to tell server which page to call for given string.

In your `Global.asax` file write following:

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{

   RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute(
      "ErrorPage",      // Route name
      "ErrorPage",      // Route URL
      "~/ErrorPage.aspx" // Web page to handle route
   );
}
```

Please refer to [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020111718/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/012710-1.aspx) post for more details.

Comment: i have written that in my global.asax page.  routes.MapPageRoute("ErrorPage", "ApplicationError", "~/Public/Error.aspx");

Comment: i just tried that string url = Page.GetRouteUrl("ErrorPage");
then i could see on trace that url=/ApplicationError?Length=9 . what does that length mean???